# Loading over 300 items at once from SQLite in Swift

Tags: swift

I am using SQLite for data storage for an application that I am working on. Everything seems to work fine but I just discovered an issue with the performance of the app when it comes to loading more than 200 or 300 items.

The app takes 2-3 seconds to load that, which to me seems a lot. I wonder if there are some techniques that I can use to speed up performance? Here's my code:

```
var users = [Users]()
 for user in try db.prepare(tableusers) {
 let u = User(username: user[username], firstname: user[firstname], lastname: user[lastname]
 users.append(u)

}
```

NOTE: I am using SQlite with SQLite.Swift-- a wrapper around Sqlite for Swift.

Comment: Observe the query being run and optimize it with [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html). Profile your app with Time Profiler to find out where the bottleneck lies. It's likely that the time is being spent inside of SQLite, but again it may not be. It's best to keep assumptions at bay, and profile.

Comment: @Anurag I did that and it looks like that all the queries with over 200 items take the same amount of time. I also tried removing some fields from the query to see if that made a difference but the time remained the same.

Comment: @Penman If you look for decent performance, you may consider using another SQLite wrapper, such as GRDB. You can hope for a x3 speed up (evidence:https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/wiki/Performance). Yet your case is still unexpectedly slow. Did you try monitoring your app with Instruments?

Comment: Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` for your query?

Comment: @Anurag: it's a simple SELECT * FROM users.

Comment: That should be really straightforward. How big is your users table? Can you post an example db file online?

Comment: @Anurag The table has a little over 6000 items. It has 4 columns, the first three are simple number fields, the last one is a text field and holds two-five lines of text. It's not a big table to be honest. Sorry cannot post the db file as it's work related.